# How to Restore a "discard my changes" file from sharepoint (edited on desktop portal)

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I was using the sharepoint on my local file viewer and when I opened it this morning I got a pop up saying if I wanted to discard my changes to the file, I selected yes, but now I realize that the file is not the last file I was editing but the file someone else was editing on the sharepoint so I have now lost all of the work that I had done. is there any way to restore the discarded changes?

I have tried the recycle folder both on my local drive and the sharepoint with no luck
I have also tried to restore previous versions but the one I am looking for does not exist

I was working on the file over a couple of days so I am surprised that there was no autosave file?

Does anyone know a way of restoring the discarded changes?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was this local? it sounds like you discarded the changes to a file you were working on in Sharepoint.  If you can't find this in the recycle bin and the previous version is not available it may not be possible to restore the work.

This may not be helpful, but here are a few things you can try:

1. Check your local backups: If you have a backup system set up on your local drive, you may be able to restore a copy of the file from a previous backup.
2. Look for a draft version of the file: Sometimes, SharePoint will create a draft version of a file if it detects that changes are being made but not yet saved. This version may contain your unsaved changes. This may be in your local profile settings, try doing a search on your hard drive for the file name.  If it doesn't turn up anything, try searching for a part of the file name.

Also, Sharepoint has the version control feature that you can use to view and restore a previous version of the file if you uploaded it at all!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried the above and it looks like the file is not there

Comment: You are very welcome- I'm sorry that there isn't better news. I've lost a lot of work while programming, writing documents, and even just stuff I was personally pursuing.  I always keep it in the back of my head to save and save often, but sometimes it gets a way from me.

Comment: did you use anything like chatgpt to write any part of this answer?